# SQL throwing an exception while i am trying to connect it with sql server authentication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have installed microsoft sql server 2008 in windows 8 and after that i have installed visual studio 2008 in my pc but now when i try to start and sql it throwing an exception.

> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.RegisteredServers.RegisteredServerException: Unable to read the list of previously registered servers on this system. Re-register your servers in the 'Registered Servers' window.

Comment: Are you able to open `Server Management Studio` and login to server?

Comment: the poor's mans test...that doesn't use "code" ... is to open Control Panel / Admin Tools / Data Sources (ODBC) .  and create a System-DSN (you can delete it later)......and try to connect.  If this doesn't work...then code won't.

Comment: I just can open it and as it load it throw an exception and if i continue with that it do not allow me to connect it